# Can I set some lines in /etc/fstab to not mount at boot?

Tags: debian, mount, fstab

I have several lines in `/etc/fstab` that rely on an encrypted disk being open. I don't want to prompt for a crypt password on boot so that other people can reboot the server without knowing the encryption password if I am away.

So I would like to setup `/etc/fstab` so that it mounts the non-encryption-dependent things at boot, but ignores certain specific lines during boot up.

After the system boots, I can then log in via SSH and open the encrypted filesystem and run `mount -av` and have it mount the rest of the lines from `/etc/fstab`.

Is there some type of flag that will make `/etc/fstab` behave this way? Or is there a similar way to achieve this effect?

Comment: you'll want the `noauto` option in fstab ... of course that does mean `mount -a` won't mount those ones ... I guess you figured out that catch 22 already

Comment: @JaromandaX That's a perfectly valid answer. If you wrote it below it could be voted on and possibly accepted by OP.

Comment: @AaronCopley - except that OP wants `mount -av` to mount it, which it won't, since `mount -av` explicitly does NOT mount entries that are `noauto` :p So, I believe an answer would get downvoted to oblivion, and rightly so :p

Comment: Write the answer. Add a sample script to mount the missing volumes. It doesn't have to be `mount -av`, any command name will do.

Comment: @JaromandaX Ah, right, I misunderstood. I just know `noauto` as the mount option he _should_ be using for this behavior. I missed that it was in conflict with how he _wants_ it to work.

Comment: I think in this case it sounds like the answer is, "use `noauto` and then have a separate mount script that explicitly mounts those mount points", which could be posted as an answer and accepted.